# python convert IplImage to Qimage

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt, qimage, iplimage

I am trying to process some videos using openCV and then put it inside pyqt Qimage...

I saw some examples to do that but they are all in C++ and I can understand python only,

Can anyone help me please ... thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to convert numpy arrays to QImage:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QImage, qRgb
import numpy as np

class NotImplementedException:
    pass

gray_color_table = [qRgb(i, i, i) for i in range(256)]

def toQImage(im, copy=False):
    if im is None:
        return QImage()

    if im.dtype == np.uint8:
        if len(im.shape) == 2:
            qim = QImage(im.data, im.shape[1], im.shape[0], im.strides[0], QImage.Format_Indexed8)
            qim.setColorTable(gray_color_table)
            return qim.copy() if copy else qim

        elif len(im.shape) == 3:
            if im.shape[2] == 3:
                qim = QImage(im.data, im.shape[1], im.shape[0], im.strides[0], QImage.Format_RGB888);
                return qim.copy() if copy else qim
            elif im.shape[2] == 4:
                qim = QImage(im.data, im.shape[1], im.shape[0], im.strides[0], QImage.Format_ARGB32);
                return qim.copy() if copy else qim

    raise NotImplementedException
```

and then just convert OpenCV's CvMat to a numpy array before calling `toQImage()`

```
arr = numpy.asarray(mat)
qim = toQImage(arr)
```

See also http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/cookbook.html for the conversion between OpenCV's CvMat and numpy arrays.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
camcapture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)       
cv.SetCaptureProperty(camcapture,cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)
cv.SetCaptureProperty(camcapture,cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720);

frame = cv.QueryFrame(camcapture)
image = QImage(frame.tostring(), frame.width, frame.height, QImage.Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped()
pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(image)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to ask the same question from cvMat to QImage conversation and I didn't find any example for python.

I solved it like this:

```
pano = cv.CreateMat(int(height),int(width),0)
cv.Zero(pano)
cv.Resize(self.image,pano)
self._data=pano.tostring('raw') 
image2=QImage(self._data,pano.width,pano.height,QtGui.QImage.Format_Indexed8)

self.imageLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap(image2))
```

Answer (score 0):

This function worked for me using QT5, using a JPEG from local disk

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage
```

---

```
def convertMatToQImage(cvImg):
    return QImage(cvImg.data, cvImg.shape[1], cvImg.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB32)
```